# how can i sort an array of structures in c

Tags: c, sorting, data-structures

I need to sort an array of structures, each one having a string that is a name.
I want to do a simple sorting using bubble sort and strcmp, but my code doesn't work, it outputs the last name I've entered for the entire loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 16
#define N 5

struct Prova {
  char nome[SIZE];
};

void sort(struct Prova *ptr) {
  char temp[SIZE];

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++) {
      if (strcmp((ptr + i)->nome, (ptr + j)->nome) < 0) {
        strcpy(temp, (ptr + i)->nome);
        strcpy((ptr + i)->nome, (ptr + j)->nome);
        strcpy(temp, (ptr + j)->nome);
      }
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  struct Prova * ptr;
  ptr = (struct Prova*) malloc(N * sizeof(struct Prova));

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    scanf(" %s", (ptr + i)->nome);
  }

  sort(ptr);

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", (ptr + i)->nome);
  }
}
```

Basically it needs to sort all the names in the structures and print them in ascending order, using the first letter of the name.

UPDATED: Later i noticed that mistake in my code, thank you all for the replies/suggestions. Now is this:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
{
  for(int j = i+1; j < N; j++)
  {
    // < 0 = Z-A  invece > 0 = A-Z
    if(strcmp((ptr+i)->nome,(ptr+j)->nome) > 0)
      {
        strcpy(temp, (ptr+i)->nome);
        strcpy((ptr+i)->nome,(ptr+j)->nome);
        strcpy((ptr+j)->nome, temp);
      }
  }

}
```

Comment: to sort an array you can use [`qsort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort)

Comment: Use `if(strcmp(ptr[j].nome,ptr[j+1].nome) < 0)` and loop up to `j < N-1`. Note also the simplified notation to index the array.

Comment: malloc statement is outside the loop. So you don' t have an array of structures, but only one structure. That' s why there is nothing to sort here.

Comment: @Alpay, that is not correct: he allocates one big array.

Comment: "but my code doesn't work" --> post the input used, output seen and output expected.  This will improve the post and lead to a rapid solution.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Yes you are right. I missed "N * " part. Sorry.

Comment: You might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: In C there is no need to cast here: `ptr = (struct Prova*) malloc(...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP mis-coded

```
    strcpy(temp, (ptr + i)->nome);
    strcpy((ptr + i)->nome, (ptr + j)->nome);
    // strcpy(temp, (ptr + j)->nome);
    strcpy((ptr + j)->nome, temp);
```

---

Many other improvements possible

1. Use `qsort()`  [@Karsten Koop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49922600/how-can-i-sort-an-array-of-structures-in-c/49923271#comment86860926_49922600)
2. Validate inputs.  Better to use `fgets()`.
3. Simplify, check and free --> `struct Prova *ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr * N); if (ptr == NULL) Handle_OutOfMemory(); ... // use ptr ... free(ptr);`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the last strcpy statement. You need to reverse the parameters like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++) {
      if (strcmp((ptr + i)->nome, (ptr + j)->nome) < 0) {
        strcpy(temp, (ptr + i)->nome);
        strcpy((ptr + i)->nome, (ptr + j)->nome);
        strcpy((ptr + j)->nome, temp);
      }
    }
  }
}
```